# Iterating over rows in a pandas dataframe with a condition to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a 720 by 720 dataframe with numerical values. I want to go through each row, compare each cell with a condition and create a new cell at the end of the row that contains the number of cells in the row that fulfills the condition(smaller or equal than some number c). So, in the end I need to have a new column added that tells me how many numbers in each row fulfill my condition.

Edit: added image of dataframe

[image: Dataframe]

Thank you!

Comment: show some sample data please, also we would try to avoid _explicitly_ looping over the dataframe as that defeats the purpose

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 0.3, 4], 'b': [0.5, 3, 0.7, 5], 'c': [2, 0.8, 1, 3]})
```

[image]

the following code generates a new column that holds the count of numbers less than or equal 2 in each row:

```
df['<= 2'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(np.where(x.values <= 2)[0]), axis=1)
```

[image]

You can modify the condition to satisfy your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the column first and then add the value in a second step. The column is there anyway once the condition applies once. Otherwise you always create a new column.